# Custom sort a list in python with mixed letters and numbers

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list containing 6 strings:

```
s1 = 'foo[2]_bar'
s2 = 'foo[2]_ant'
s3 = 'foo[1]_bar'
s4 = 'foo[1]_ant'
s5 = 'foo[10]_bar'
s6 = 'foo[10]_ant'
str_arr = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]
```

If I use **`str_arr.sort()`** the order comes out like this:

```
foo[10]_ant
foo[10]_bar
foo[1]_ant
foo[1]_bar
foo[2]_ant
foo[2]_bar
```

However, I need the order to take more precedence of alphabetical sorting, meaning `"ant"` should come before `"bar"` in all cases, but also sub-sorting for numerical order.

So I need the output to be like this but I don't know how to accomplish this:

```
foo[1]_ant
foo[2]_ant
foo[10]_ant
foo[1]_bar
foo[2]_bar
foo[10]_bar
```

I'm not sure if there's some sort of filter or lambda function I can use but I can barely understand a lot of lambda functions I see on here.

Comment: So, if the text is "prefix[index]_suffix" then sort by prefix, then suffix, then index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `lambda` with multiple conditions. The conditions are prioritized from left-to-right:

Code:

```
s1 = 'foo[2]_bar'
s2 = 'foo[2]_ant'
s3 = 'foo[1]_bar'
s4 = 'foo[1]_ant'
s5 = 'foo[10]_bar'
s6 = 'foo[10]_ant'
str_arr = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]

str_arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[x.find("_")+1:], int(x[x.find("[")+1:x.find("]")])))
print(str_arr)
```

Output:

```
['foo[1]_ant', 'foo[2]_ant', 'foo[10]_ant', 'foo[1]_bar', 'foo[2]_bar', 'foo[10]_bar']
```

***How it works:***

(For every entry `x`)

From left-to-right we have the conditions:

1. `x[x.find("_")+1:]`
   This is the first sorting condition. It will sort based on the word that comes after the underscore. Here, we slice the string by finding the underscore, and returning the portion of the string that occurs after it.
2. `int(x[x.find("[")+1:x.find("]")])`
   This is the second sorting condition. It will sort based on the `int` between the `[]` in the string. It slices the string so we are left with only that number, then it converts that number to an `int`, and compares the `int` to the integers in the other strings.

As stated above, using a `lambda` with multiple conditions means it will prioritize the sorting conditions from left-to-right. Here, we prioritize sorting by the last word (so `ant` always comes before `bar`), and then sorting by the integer (so 1...ant comes before 2...ant and so on.

Comment: I like this suggestion and thanks for explaining the lambda function but I added two additional stings to test it and it didn't produce the correct results. 
`s7 = 'foo[2]_bank'` and `s8 = 'foo[2]_ace'` - this results in:
`['foo[1]_ant', 'foo[2]_ace', 'foo[2]_ant', 'foo[10]_ant', 'foo[1]_bar', 'foo[2]_bank', 'foo[2]_bar', 'foo[10]_bar']`

Comment: @winger I apologize -- I made a typo. There should be a colon `:` after `x.find("_")+1` within the brackets. I wrote the correct code in my explanation but not in the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks Ryan! This works but I have found a testcase where it doesn't. For instance, if you replace all strings to begin with `all_foo` instead of `foo`.

Comment: Would there perhaps be a way to adjust it for slightly more complex strings? For instance, given `str_arr = ['all_foo[0]_chnl_one/send_xi[8]', 'all_foo[0]_channel/upper_channel/read_n', 'all_foo[1]_chnl_one/send_xi[8]', 'all_foo[1]_channel/upper_channel/read_n', 'all_foo[1]_channel/upper_channel/read_all_n']` it gives the output: `['all_foo[1]_channel/upper_channel/read_all_n', 'all_foo[0]_channel/upper_channel/read_n', 'all_foo[1]_channel/upper_channel/read_n', 'all_foo[0]_chnl_one/send_xi[8]', 'all_foo[1]_chnl_one/send_xi[8]']`

Comment: Yes, `lambda` can take many conditions. You just have to decide the order of the hierarchy. Also, to account for a different prefix, you can add that as a sorting condition.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Ryan! Answer accepted.

Comment: FYI, I changed your lambda function to `key=lambda x: (x[x.find("]_")+1:` which appears to fix the issue I had with more complex strings.

Comment: I've run into one issue here. There are a couple of strings containing no integers e.g. `s0 = 'all_foo_bar'`. This results in _`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`_. How can I adjust this, so that it only executes the int section if the string contains an integer? I've tried to add an if condition but it doesn't like the syntax: `str_arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[x.find("]_")+1:], int(x[x.find("[")+1:x.find("]")]) if any(char.isdigit() for char in x)))`

Comment: @winger you probably want a ternary operator so you can perform an if-statement in-place: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-operator-in-python/. make the condition reflect if there is an int, and set a default value if there isn't, so the sort condition doesn't change anything else.

Comment: @winger you could also wrap the sort in a try-except block, to detect if an error is thrown when you try to cast an invalid literal to an `int`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `re`:

```py
import re

s1 = "foo[2]_bar"
s2 = "foo[2]_ant"
s3 = "foo[1]_bar"
s4 = "foo[1]_ant"
s5 = "foo[10]_bar"
s6 = "foo[10]_ant"
str_arr = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]

pat = re.compile(r"\[(\d+)\]_(.*)")

print(sorted(str_arr, key=lambda k: ((m := pat.search(k))[2], int(m[1]))))
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "foo[1]_ant",
    "foo[2]_ant",
    "foo[10]_ant",
    "foo[1]_bar",
    "foo[2]_bar",
    "foo[10]_bar",
]
```

---

EDIT: Version without `:=`

```py
import re

s1 = "foo[2]_bar"
s2 = "foo[2]_ant"
s3 = "foo[1]_bar"
s4 = "foo[1]_ant"
s5 = "foo[10]_bar"
s6 = "foo[10]_ant"
str_arr = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]

pat = re.compile(r"\[(\d+)\]_(.*)")


def key_fn(x):
    a, b = pat.search(x).groups()
    return b, int(a)


print(sorted(str_arr, key=key_fn))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this code only works in v3.8 onwards due to the `:=` operator. I'm unable to test it on my current python version.

Comment: @winger I've added version without `:=`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

make a custom sort function and then pass it as a key

You can return multiple objects from your custom sort function and priority will be given on the basis of order of the returning.

```
s1 = 'foo[2]_bar'
s2 = 'foo[2]_ant'
s3 = 'foo[1]_bar'
s4 = 'foo[1]_ant'
s5 = 'foo[10]_bar'
s6 = 'foo[10]_ant'
str_arr = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]

def custom_sort(x):
    last_str = x.split("_")[-1]
    num = x[x.index("[")+1: x.index("]")]
    return last_str, int(num)

for i in (sorted(str_arr, key=custom_sort)):
    print(i)
```